# Is it possible to switch to active Linux installation from Recovery mode?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, login, system-recovery

Noob here. I have Pop OS 20.04 installed on my laptop. I've been getting these sudden freeze-outs where I get dialogues like "disk is read-only" when I'm doing something. Then I restart, and I can't log in anymore. I get a black screen and that's it.
Now I've tried going into recovery mode and using some tweaks provided on system76's blog, and at times they work.
What I'd like to know is,
**Is there a way to boot into Recovery mode, and switch to my native installation from within, without restarting?**

Comment: Something like `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target`?

Comment: @rfmodulator I haven't used either. Perhaps these should work. I'll try and get back

Comment: @rfmodulator I tried both these commands, nothing happened.

Comment: *nothing?* no change, no error, no output message at all?

Comment: @rfmodulator nothing. I have to repeatedly do chroot from recovery and then restart. I tried fsck and restart a couple of times and it worked.